# node Js + JS input = document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

there is a node JS script (app.js) that sends a letter to the mail:

```
const { response } = require("express");
const express = require("express");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

//
function sendEmail(tel) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var tranporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: ,
        pass: ,
      },
    });
    const mail_configs = {
      from: "myEmail",
      to: "artemdvd@mail.ru",
      subject: "Testing Koding 101 Email",
      text: "tel",
    };
    tranporter.sendMail(mail_configs, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return reject({ message: "An error has occured" });
      }
      return resolve({ message: "Email sent succesfuly" });
    });
  });
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  sendEmail()
    .then((response) => res.send(response.message))
    .catch((error) => res.status(500).send(error.message));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`nodemailerProject is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

there is a button in other js file which run this js script and send email when I push the button:

```
let input = document.getElementById("phonenumber");

head.addEventListener("click", function () {
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
});
```

there is an imput field for text a message in html file

```
<input id="phonenumber" class="text-order" type="text"
        placeholder="___________"'/>
```

how to make to send this input value in email message when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) accepts a second parameter, an options object. This is where you would pass your input. In your case, you'll need to capture the value of the input. So if you have:

`let input = document.getElementById("phonenumber");`

then you should be able to access the value with `input.value`. If you send that in the body property of your options object, it should show up in the request body on the server.

Something like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/", {
  body: JSON.stringify(input.value)
})
```

I see that you're also listening for the click on another element (`head`). If that's the case, then you'll probably need an `onChange` handler on the input which stores the value somewhere locally. Then when the user clicks the other element, you have it ready to pass into the fetch options.

Here's an example of the syntax for sending options (borrowed from the docs I shared above), demonstrating the different options it will accept:

```
// Example POST method implementation:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData('https://example.com/answer', { answer: 42 })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
  });
```